# Node.js - ORM with hierarchical data support

Tags: node.js, orm, sails.js, waterline

Like the title says i am looking for an ORM that supports hierarchical data.
For example i will need to represent a relation like this (category with subcategories and so on...):

```
CREATE TABLE "category" 
  (
     "id"          SERIAL       PRIMARY KEY,
     "parent"      INTEGER      NULL DEFAULT NULL REFERENCES "category" ("id")
     "name"        VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL UNIQUE,
     "description" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
     "sort_order"  INTEGER      NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  );
```

Is there any one that can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [**sails.js**](http://sailsjs.org/). Their Waterline ORM has support for dozens of databases and has excellent relational support, and it has a huge community surrounding it.

From the docs:

> You can do all the same things you might be used to (one-to-many,
>   many-to-many), but you can also assign multiple named associations
>   per-model (for instance, a cake might have two collections of people:
>   "havers" and "eaters"). Better yet, you can assign different models to
>   different databases, and your associations/joins will still work--
>   even across NoSQL and relational boundries. Sails has no problem
>   implicitly/automatically joining a MySQL table with a Mongo collection
>   and vice versa.